# why cant we assign a value to global variables using an expression in C ?

Tags: c

In the below code snippet , I am trying to assign a value to a global variable using an expression but it gives the error "**initializer element is not constant**" ,I am unable to get the logic behind this ,please clarify this .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a=8;
int b=a+9;
int main()
{
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a global variable using an expression. But only inside a function. As said by the compiler/linker, outside a function you can initialize variables only to constant. This is because, outside a function, no code can be executed and the variables are initialized to constant value by the compiler/linker at build time. Note that if you don't init the variable (outside a function), the default initialization is to 0.
To make it work you should write

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a=8;
int b;
int main()
{
   b=a+9;
   printf("%d",b);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can very well initialize a global variable outside a function with an expression - As long as it is a *constant* expression. And an expression containing a variable like in the example *per definitionem* isn't `const`

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that global variables are initialized in compiling time,
and you are trying to initialize `b=a+9;`  as an operation that must be done in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

As `b` is of arithmetic type and has static storage duration, its initializer has to satisfy the rules of arithmetic constant expressions (C11 §6.6 Expressions):

> **8**    An arithmetic constant expression shall have arithmetic type and
>   shall only have
>        operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character
>        constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, and _Alignof
>        expressions.
>
> Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert
>        arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a sizeof or
>        _Alignof operator.

`int b=a+9;` doesn't.